# compare space complexity within two reverse linkedList algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, reverse, space-complexity

```
public static Node reverseLinkedList1(Node head) {
    if(head == null) return null;
    Node node = null;
    while(head != null) {
      Node newNode = new Node(head.data);
      newNode.next = node;
      node = newNode;
      head = head.next;
    } 
    return node;       
  }

  public static Node reverseLinkedList2(Node head) {
    if(head == null) return null;
    Node node = null;
    while(head != null) {
      Node next = head.next;
      head.next = node;
      node = head;
      head = next;
    }
    return node;
  }
```

**Are these two algorithm same SPACE COMPLEXITY?
I know the second one is O(1) space complexity,
What about the first one? O(N) or O(1)?**

Comment: What do you think? What is the one difference between the two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first algorithm has O(N) as space complexity, because you are building a new `LinkedList`.

Let's take a look at the algorithm with an example list

```
Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3 -> null
```

When you enter the while loop for the first time, you will create a new Node `Node1*` with the data of `Node1` and nothing has been modified to the original `LinkedList`. You just shuffled some local variables, resulting in

```
Node1 -> Node2 (head) -> Node3 -> null
node = Node1* -> `null`
```

After the second while loop. Note that Node1 is still in the original list.

```
Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3 (head) -> null
node = Node2* -> Node1* -> null
```

After the third time

```
Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3 -> null (head)
node = Node3* -> Node2* -> Node1* -> null
```

At this point, you have two lists of the same size.

Of course, I have only looked at the number of `Node` instances. Since you share the data between the nodes, the actual overhead is not that big.

The benefit of the first algorithm is of course that your original `LinkedList` is still intact, which isn't the case for your second algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are creating `N` new objects, so you are consuming space `O(N)`. At the end of the method, the original list is `still holding` reference as it was passed. You should set to null these reference so they will be available for `garbage collection` by JVM.

I have added a separate `temp` variable for holding the current `head`, once we extract the `head.next`, we can set `head.next=null`. As now these object are not referenced by anybody will become eligible for garbage collection.

```
public static Node reverseLinkedList1(Node head) {
  if(head == null) return null;
  Node node = null;
  Node temp;
  while(head != null) {
    Node newNode = new Node(head.data);
    newNode.next = node;
    node = newNode;
    temp = head;
    head = head.next;
    temp.next = null;
  }
  return node;
}
```